# How can I get model names from inside my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of models in a sub-directory that inherit from a model in the models root directory.  I want to be able to set a class variable in another model that lists each inherited model class.

i.e

```
@@groups = sub_models.map do { |model| model.class.to_s }
```

Not sure how to get at this info though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a full answer [here](http://markmail.org/message/betc7jcmtfnoa6r5#query:list%20models%20rails+page:1+mid:flnnpjqg7gstadwk+state:results). Basically, you can either troll through the files or monkey-patch Class (or ActiveRecord). Those are two ways to go, at least.

**Edit:** On second thought, Rails won't load your Models until necessary, so while the "files" way seems weak, it's probably your only option (unless you want to do something in your models themselves).

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, in production env this should work

```
Object.subclasses_of ClassInModelDir
```

You have to load the files manually If Rails.env.development?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this unless you preload your descendant models. This is the reason why it is prudent to reengineer your code to use `Class#ancestors` instead of `descendants` (also descendants are not a core Ruby feature).